# android web service fails

Tags: java, android, web-services

hello guys I have a web service to help me do the login process
but when I run the code I receive error says "the application has stopped unexpectedly........

here is my web service :

```
package org.webserv.ws;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class hello {
    public String authentication(String userName,String password) {
        String retrievedUserName = "";  
        String retrievedPassword = "";
        String status = "";

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/android           app.","","admin");
            PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user account info. WHERE    username = '"+userName+"'AND password = '"+password+"'");
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

            while(result.next()){
                retrievedUserName = result.getString("username");
                retrievedPassword = result.getString("password");
            }

            if(retrievedUserName.equals(userName)&&retrievedPassword.equals(password)){
                status = "Success!";
            }
            else { status = "Login fail!!!"; }

        }
        catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return status; 
    }
}
```

and here goes the logcat

> 01-28 15:03:32.212: E/AndroidRuntime(314): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-28
>   15:03:32.212: E/AndroidRuntime(314): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject 01-28 15:03:32.212:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(314):    at
>   com.androidlogin.ws.AndroidLoginExampleActivity.loginAction(AndroidLoginExampleActivity.java:38)
>   01-28 15:03:32.212: E/AndroidRuntime(314):    at
>   com.androidlogin.ws.AndroidLoginExampleActivity.access$0(AndroidLoginExampleActivity.java:37)
>   01-28 15:03:32.212: E/AndroidRuntime(314):    at
>   com.androidlogin.ws.AndroidLoginExampleActivity$1.onClick(AndroidLoginExampleActivity.java:31)
>   01-28 15:03:32.212: E/AndroidRuntime(314):    at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408) 01-28 15:03:32.212:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(314):    at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816) 01-28 15:03:32.212:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(314):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 01-28
>   15:03:32.212: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 01-28
>   15:03:32.212: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 01-28 15:03:32.212:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(314):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 01-28
>   15:03:32.212: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-28
>   15:03:32.212: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 01-28 15:03:32.212:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(314):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   01-28 15:03:32.212: E/AndroidRuntime(314):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 01-28
>   15:03:32.212: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-28 15:03:38.001:
>   I/Process(314): Sending signal. PID: 314 SIG: 9

and  this is the AndroidLoginExampleActivity.java   file

```
package com.androidlogin.ws;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidLoginExampleActivity extends Activity {
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.webserv.org";
private final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/androidapp./services/hello?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.webserv.org/authentication";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "authentication";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            loginAction();

        }
    });
}

private void loginAction(){
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
    String user_Name = userName.getText().toString();
    EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
    String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

  //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
    unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
    unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

  //Pass value for Password variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
    passwordProp.setName("password");
    passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
    passwordProp.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(passwordProp);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
           SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

           TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
           result.setText(response.toString());

    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
   }
```

}

Comment: What is written on AndroidLoginExampleActivity.java:38 and have you copied com.mysql.jdbc.Driver jar file lib folder of application.

Comment: I've add the .java file in the edition of the main question I have imported the mysql connector to the web server application

Comment: @TGMCians Looks to me like it may be the initialization of `SoapObject`

Comment: empty line.....nothing  written

Comment: @user1794499 How comes it possible?? I have posted answer please try this it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Add this jar file  /libs folder so `Eclipse ADT` automatically adds your jars to the buildpath of your application. I hope this will help you.

Thanks!!

Comment: I have ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-RC.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar in the AndroidLoginExample project

Comment: @user1794499  Clean the project and then re-run it and copy this jar files in 'libs' folder not 'lib'..

Comment: :'( still have the same thing

Comment: @user1794499  First tell me where this error occur and give that line to me then we can help you otherwise its is impossible for us. You are saying nothing is written on AndroidLoginExampleActivity.java:38 How comes its possible for us analyze the problem..

Comment: sorry I referred to line 39-my baaaad-....but line 38 has this one        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); you may check the complete code above